Factor Analysis with Multiple Imputation
I have a dataset with 49 Items of a questionnaire (ordinal; 0,1,2,3,4) with 5 diagnostic group of samples (n1: 50, n2: 25; n3:30, n4:23, n5:60). However, the dataset have missings like for 10-12 individuals up to 10% missings across all items; missing at random). I want to conduct a factor analysis in R like with the principal function of the "psych" package with 9 factor solution and varimax rotation.
My question is how can I conduct a multiple imputation and pool the factor loadings and other PCA parameters (e.g., explained variance, item complexity, commonalities)
Single imputation works fine with the mice package using "polr" (proportional odds logistic regression). However I want to do the multiple imputation to have most possible accurate results.
I can conduct PCAs with all imputed datasets. But how can I pool other parameters of the PCAs taking into account the variances?

Welcome to CV. A couple points 1) Requests for code are off topic here. Your post has both statistical and coding parts, but you might want to remove the code request. 2) Be very careful . The signs of factor loadings are arbitrary, so pooling can make a mess. Also, the order of the factors can switch  around, if they account for roughly equal amounts of variance.
